# Use user id as a variable inside Angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I use the following code to retrieve and filter my movie records,

```
.movie_container{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies | orderBy:'release_date' | filter:{user_id: user_id} "}
```

The filter checks what movies correspond with the given `user_id` in the filter. The code for the filter is this,

```
var user_id = "4"
$scope.user_id = user_id;
```

So now the `ng-repeat` only shows the results with the `user_id` of 4. But ofcourse I want the variable `user_id` to be the current users ID and not a static number.

Is it possible to get the current users ID and insert it into the variable value of `user_id`?

I use the Rails Devise gem for my login without the AngularJS interaction.

Comment: I suppose you must already be having a way to get the authenticated user information. If you do, then simply store the user id from the logged in user info into the $scope.user_id and everything will work out the way you want it to.

Comment: @ShekharChikara I'm using the Rails Devise gem for my authentication. The point is that I'm not sure on how to acces the user id in Angular.

Comment: How does your authorization work within angular? Missing some critical information here

Comment: Are you using angular-devise? or some other implementation? In any case, the devise authentication returns the authenticated user and you should be able to inject that into your controller and use the user's id.

Comment: @show-me-the-code I am not using the angular-devise. I'm using the rails devise gem. I know Devise returns a user id, but I don't know how to store it in a AngularJS controller.

Comment: Is login in separate page? If so can pass user profile to js variable in script tag. Authentication process flow is still not clear

Comment: @charlietfl What does it matter if it's a seperate page? Every user has a id. I just want to know how to insert that id into a variable in a Angular controller.

Comment: it matters in that you have not explained your auth process flow . If auth is done from within angular then store in auth service. Otherwise do as I suggested. Angular is javascript so all scope rules for the language apply. A variable in script tag can be read from anywhere in the app

Comment: I've explained that I'm using a rails gem called Devise for my authentication so the authentication is not done with an Angular hook. I don't undestand what you mean with `a variable in script tag' . I can acces the user data through localhost:3000/users.json if that is helpfull.

Comment: The question here is how does your AngularJs application know that the user is authenticated? You mentioned devise gem but it doesn't tell how you send the user credentials and what you get as a response from the javascript. The key to finding the user's id lies in the response of your user authentication process.